# highcharts dynamic data from php

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

I am trying to plot a chart (Spline) using data that is dynamically generated from PHP. The JavaScript library I am using for this purpose is HighCharts.

The PHP generates an array of values in the format like

```
array(
      array("1304294461000",69,"1304899261000",28),
      array("1304294431000",3,"1304899161000",32)
)
```

which I am then passing onto a javascript array using json_encode. However, when I push these values as data, it doesn't seem to be working.

For example, here's an example with relevant code snippets like -

```
 var namesArr = <?php echo json_encode($namesArr); ?>;

 var progressTrendsData = <?php echo json_encode($progressTrendsData); ?>;
 var chart;
 var options = {
     chart: {
         renderTo: 'trendsDiv',
         type: 'spline'
     },
     series: [{
     name: '',
     data: []
     }]
 };

 for(var i=0;i<namesArr.length;i++) {
    options.series.push({
            name: namesArr[i],
            data: progressTrendsData[i]
    });
 }

 chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

The options contain other relevant data needed for the chart of course. 
However, the only thing the above code is doing is plotting a single value at the date January 1 irrespective of the actual data that is being pushed.

Comment: Your code kinda works.  I add in the values based on what would be subbed in from the PHP.  See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/Wstgr/.  One thing, I think you mean the array to be point pairs [[[1304294461000,69],[1304899261000,28]],[[1304294431000,3],[1304899161000,32]]] or from PHP array(
      array(array(1304294461000,69),array(1304899261000,28)),
      array(array(1304294431000,3),array(1304899161000,32))
)

Comment: Yeah, that works if you directly sub-in the values, but doesn't otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to agree w/Mark on this.  It is hard to tell exactly your data is supposed to end up looking like though.  Try looking at the data loading portion of the ajax data example on the highcharts [demo page](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax).

**UPDATE:**

Try the following pseudocode:

```
var chart;
var options = {
     chart: {
         renderTo: 'trendsDiv',
         type: 'spline'
     },
     series: [{
     name: '',
     data: []
     }]
 };

var seriesInfo=[];
seriesInfo[0]={"name":"Series A","data":[]};
seriesInfo[1]={"name":"Series B","data":[]};

//Loop over the series and populate the data
seriesInfo[0].data.push({x:<insert Series A timestamp>,y:<insert Series A y value>});
seriesInfo[1].data.push({x:<insert Series B timestamp>,y:<insert Series B y value>});

options.series.push(seriesInfo[0]);
options.series.push(seriesInfo[1]);

chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Comment: The data consists of time, value pairs

Comment: No, I can change them if required

Comment: Ok, so I figured the problem is that the time part of the pair is being returned as a string, and since I am on a 32-bit system, I can't convert it to an int. What would be the best option in this case?